# Tool Tip text binding and Modal dialog not working with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, tooltip, modal-dialog, qtip

I have created this fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/adi85/mBpJB/8/

I'm not able to bind data to tool tip and also i'm trying to use modal dialog box which is not working because of template binding in knockout.

```
<table class="tbl" id="dash" >    
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: course">
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#" id="qtipselector_01" data-bind="text: title, loadqtip: true"></a></td>
          <div id="TooltipContent_01" class="hidden"><!--for each tr there will be a tool tip-->
     <!-- in the below a tag the bidning is not working and also the dialog box is not working for me --> 
            <a data-bind="text: title" data-reveal-id="dialog" data-animation="fade"> Enroll </a>
          </div>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Console is your Friend:

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: title is not defined;
Bindings value: text: title

Looks to me like you needed to access the course observableArray items slightly differently.

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/mBpJB/6/

```
<table class="tbl" id="dash" >    
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: course">
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#" id="qtipselector_01" data-bind="text: $data.title, loadqtip: true"></a></td>
          <div id="TooltipContent_01" class="hidden">
            <a data-bind="text: $data.title" data-reveal-id="dialog" data-animation="fade"> Enroll </a>
          </div>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

All I did, in essence, was tell it to access $data.title, instead of title. Can't remember at the moment why that would work, and just calling title wouldn't, but check out the Fiddle and maybe that will get you where you need to go.

Comment: the code is not giving error with $data.title,  but tool tip is still not showing title text. Also i need a dialog box to come up on click of one of the tool tip, can you show me an example here how to do that.